# Exception object as parameter in dll file

Tags: c#

A main method in my project (which is going to be compiled as dll file) needs Exception class object as parameter. Can I pass an object as a parameter for a method from dll file?

Comment: Yes, the same as you would pass any other parameter.

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pass Exceptions. They are just like any class, [they inherit from `System.Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx), and they can be passed just like any other parameter.